# Node JS toLocaleTimeString acting Funny in different Environments Server VS Laptop

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime

So on my laptop (mac book pro) I pull up my bash and hit node to work on some date objects

I get this response:

```
$node
> var d = new Date();
Sat Oct 03 2015 03:48:41 GMT-0700 (PDT)
> d.toLocaleTimeString();
'3:48:41 AM'
> d.toLocaleTimeString('en-US', { hour: '2-digit', minute:'2-digit' });
'3:48 AM'
```

So here i get the exact response i need

Now when i do this on my server (cent OS) I get a different response

```
> var d = new Date();
undefined
> d.toLocaleTimeString();
'03:13:19'
> d.toLocaleTimeString('en-US');
'03:13:19'
> d.toLocaleTimeString('en-US', {hour12:true});
'03:13:19'
> d.toLocaleTimeString('en-US', { hour: '2-digit', minute:'2-digit' });
'03:13:19'
>FML
```

can anyone explain why it dose not work on my server and if there is a way to fix it?

Comment: same node version? which vers?

Comment: on server v0.10.36 laptop v4.0.0

Comment: do you get the same result on your laptop if you use v0.10.36 there?

Comment: also does the `date` command return reasonable things on both systems?

Comment: I don't think it is the version of node although i am updating it now to 4.0.0
you can see above the two different responses i get

Comment: not `new Date()` - there is a command you can run on the shell - `date`.  See http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/timedate.html

Comment: Hey @NG. you are a genius is was the version of node Thank you so much man !!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like toLocaleTimeString is not working well with the way you server is configured.

First, check the time zone in your server.  See https://chrisjean.com/change-timezone-in-centos.

The other thing that will help is to use a library like `moment` that makes it easy and formats consistently:

```
var moment = require('moment');
console.log(moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'));
```